# Misplaced/Overlapping Navigation Item Text on iOS 10

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ios-app-feed

The bug displayed in the attached screenshot occurs consistently for me while running the developer beta of iOS 10 using v1.5.2 of the Stack Exchange app on an iPhone 6.

I was able to recreate this by simply tapping on any question or answer in my feed with a long title. This doesn't appear to be a bug with iOS 10 *itself* since I haven't seen it in other apps, but I could be wrong.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Who says this is a bug in the app and not iOS?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I mentioned that possibility in the last paragraph of my post. Figured it was still worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.5.3.

Whenever the title view's content changes, the app resizes the title view to match the contents, then calls `superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` to get it to the correct size.  This supports the cases where the text is very long and should take up all the space, and the case where the text is very short and can be centered in the available space.

In iOS 10, updating the titleView's bounds didn't automatically invalidate the layout so I've added `superview?.setNeedsLayout()`.